# How can I exclude the border size when setting the size for a C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# Windows Forms application and when I set the size of my form it includes the border size.

How can I set the size of only the center area? (with borders enabled, of course.)

Comment: Usually what I do is set the border to none, size my window, then change the border back to normal.

Comment: Use `ClientSize`